# Values returned from class revert to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, object, webforms

I create an new Contractor object "gc" that calls a method GetContractor() to return all the properties. The results it is returning is correct, however the "gc" object shows all "NULL". I assume I doing something incorrectly in my aspx.cs page?

aspx.cs

```
protected void fvWasteCollected_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert")){
       ValidationSummaryWasteDetail.ValidationGroup = "WasteReceivedDetail";
       if (IsValid) {
           odsMRWWasteCollectedDetail.InsertParameters["WasteTypeId"].DefaultValue = ddlWasteCollectedType.SelectedValue;
           odsMRWWasteCollectedDetail.InsertParameters["DisposalMethodId"].DefaultValue = ddl_disposalMethod.SelectedValue;          
           Contractor gc = new Contractor();
           gc.GetContractor(2);
           var contractorName = gc.MRWContractorName;
        }
    }
}
```

.cs

```
public class Contractor
{
  public Contractor GetContractor(int MRWContractorId)
    {
        using (DataAccessLINQDataContext db = new DataAccessLINQDataContext())
        {
            var result = db.MRWContractors.Where(c => c.MRWContractorId == MRWContractorId).Select(c => new Contractor
                {
                    MRWContractorId = c.MRWContractorId,
                    MRWContractorName = c.MRWContractorName,
                    MRWContractorAddress = c.MRWContractorAddress,
                    MRWContractorCity = c.MRWContractorCity,
                    MRWContractorStateCode = c.MRWContractorStateCode,
                    MRWContractorZipCode = c.MRWContractorZipCode,
                    MRWContractorPhone = c.MRWContractorPhone,
                    MRWContractorFax = c.MRWContractorFax,
                    MRWContractorEmail = c.MRWContractorEmail
                }).SingleOrDefault();

            return result;
        }
    }

    public int MRWContractorId { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorName { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorAddress { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorCity { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorStateCode { get; set; }
    public int? MRWContractorZipCode { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorPhone { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorFax { get; set; }
    public string MRWContractorEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loosing the value of `gc` when you dont assign it to something.

Try this instead:

```
var contractor = gc.GetContractor(2);
var contractorName = contractor.MRWContractorName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating one empty instance of the object that is only used to call the `GetContractor` method. The `GetContractor` method creates another instance that contains data, which is returned, but you just throw that instance away and expect the data to be available in the first instance that never got populated.

Make the `GetContractor` method static so that you don't need an instance to call it:

```
public static Contractor GetContractor(int MRWContractorId)
```

Now you can call the method to get that instance that contains the data, without first creating an empty instance:

```
Contractor gc = Contractor.GetContractor(2);
string contractorName = gc.MRWContractorName;
```

Comment: I liked the alternate method you give here. Very helpful in bettering my skills! I went and used it!